# Custom cell resize Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

When the data load's it show the perfect constrain's and the data is shown perfectly with perfect spacing...

Please have a view to the attachment when table load's:

[image]

When we have less title then it show's spacing:

[image]

I am loading the data from files:

Code is as follow's:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Customviewcell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:justThumbs[indexPath.row]];
    cell.Customimage.image=image;

    cell.CustomTitle.text=justTitles[indexPath.row];
    [cell.CustomTitle sizeToFit];


    NSString * htmlString =justDesc[indexPath.row];
    NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    cell.CustomDes.attributedText=attrStr;

    [cell.CustomDes sizeToFit];
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}
```

Loading data from file as follow's:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [tableviewcustom reloadData];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL * url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"services" withExtension:@"plist"];
    Servicestitle = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];
    justTitles = [Servicestitle objectForKey:@"Title"];
    justThumbs= [Servicestitle objectForKey:@"Thumbnail"];
    justDesc=[Servicestitle objectForKey:@"Description"];

    tableviewcustom.estimatedRowHeight = 150;
    tableviewcustom.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    [tableviewcustom reloadData];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Storyboard as follow's:

[image]

CustomDes Constrain's:
[image]

Adding Background to title and desc:

[image]

First 3 cell's:

[image]

after first 3 cell's:

[image]

Thanks indeed for your help.

Comment: Hi Talha Aslam...My view is that Is it necessary to user attributed text ?

Comment: If you are not using attributed text then just remove the following line. -----cell.CustomDes.attributedText=attrStr ----- and write ----cell.CustomDes.text=attrStr.

Comment: @JAGAT yes because it's html and parsing html

Comment: What are the constraints on CustomDes?

Comment: @beyowulf updated please check question again!

Comment: automatically add spacing after 3 cell's

Comment: Have you tried changing the background color of title and des to see how they're being laid out? Seems like there might be a carriage return in the title or something.

Comment: @beyowulf updated question attached the image with background's applied, the first 3 cell's are perfect the issue is after first 3 cells

Comment: Yes now run the app and see what's happening at run time

Comment: @beyowulf title take allot of padding at bottom after first 3 cell's

Comment: Meaning you're seeing a lot of red or your seeing a lot of white in between red and blue?

Comment: @beyowulf i am seeing allot of red after first 3 cell's

Comment: @beyowulf let me attach another screenshot.

Comment: @beyowulf please check question updated with screenshot's

Comment: You should check the constraints on title. You should also try logging attrStr to the console to see if there's a carriage return in the string. Or say cell.CustomTitle.lines = 1 if possible.

Comment: @beyowulf can you help regarding console new on ios

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", attrStr) or NSLog(@"%@",[attrStr string])

Comment: @beyowulf it have a string

Comment: @beyowulf the issue raises after 3 cell's at forth cell we are facing the issue first three cell's are perfect

Comment: Yeah, I'm saying log something like: NSLog(@"%@ attributedString",[attrStr string]) and if attributedString is on a different line from the actual string you'll know that the html has <br /> in it, and that why the title is too big.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use this TableView delegate's method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: I am using custom resizing IOS 8.